# How this Laravel Provider works?

Tags: laravel

I get the fundamentals of Service Providers in Laravel 9.X, so I followed [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hy0oieokjtQ) on YouTube and the tutor used this code to hand out a variable to a webpage:

```php
public function boot()
    {
        view()->composer('*', function ($view) {
            $someRandomVariable = "Hello";
            return $view->with('tests', $someRandomVariable);
        });
    }
```

I understand everything **except** the `composer('*', ...)` thing, anyone got a hint? It works somehow and I dont know why.

Comment: `*` is a wildcard matching _any_ view.

Comment: So that means the variable is available in all define views ?

Comment: Correct. The `tests` variable will be available in all views.

Comment: And what is the composer(…) function?

Comment: The [`composer`](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Contracts/View/Factory.html#method_composer) function is used to inform Laravel on what to do when composing the view.

Comment: it isn't making it available to all views, what is happening is that composer is running for all views, which means that is executed for every single view rendered ... if you wanted to share something with every view you would use a view 'share' instead which would run once and share data with every view

Answer (score 0):

The composer method accepts the * character as a wildcard, allowing you to attach a composer to all views:

```
View::composer('*', function ($view) {
    //
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).